# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Products'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to display the products after fetching them and everything works fine but I have some error with TS in the destructuring statement.

Here is my fetching function:

```
export async function fetchAllProducts() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const data = res.data;
    return {
      data
    }
  } catch(err) {
    if(err instanceof AxiosError)
      return {
        error: err.message
      }
  }
}
```

And then I use it in a server component:

```
export default async function StorePage() {
 const { data, error }: Products = await fetchAllProducts(); //the problem is in this line (data and error are underlined) 
  
  return (
    <section className='section'>
      <div className='section__inner'>
        <h4 className='section__title'>Products</h4>
        {error && <span>{error}</span>}
        {!data && !error && <span>loading...</span>}
        <div className='section__content products-container'>
          {!error && data && data?.length > 0 && data.map((product: ProductProps) => <ProductCard key = {product.id}  {...product}/>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

When I destructure I get this error:

> Type '{ data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: string; data?:
> undefined; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Products'.   Type
> 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Products'.

Here are my types:

```
export type Products = {
  data: ProductProps[] | null;
  error: string | undefined;
}


export type ProductProps = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  price: number;
  rating: {
    rate: number,
    count: number
  }
}
```

So, I was wondering if the problem was connected to the fetch function, should I add types there or is there another issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
export type Products = {
    data: ProductProps[] | null;
    error: string | undefined;
}
```

the `data` property has either to be a `ProductProps[]` or `null`. But in case of an error during `fetchAllProducts`

```
 const { data, error }: Products = await fetchAllProducts();
```

the result of `fetchAllProducts` will be

```
{
   error: string
}
```

ie, no `data`, ie `data == undefined` which is not allowed in a valid instance of the `Products` type ... Change the return value in case of an exception to

```
return {
  error: err.message,
  data: null
}
```

Also in your `Products`, the `error` is a mandatory property, ie it can have the value of `undefined` but it has to exist. If you want it to be optional, define your `Products` as follows

```
export type Products = {
  data: ProductProps[] | null;
  error?: string;
}
```

See this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKClAJgQ2DgLigGdgAnASwDsBzAGigygjLIHsyjTLaoAfKAFcqWCADNqELGgC+aNKEiwATElRNc+LuWr0mLdmQD82njVny0AGwjAowOEXhqU2PISgAiHMSxjPMgDc1rb2yk6qyK6aHt6+-kFoQA) to see the difference.

Furthermore, you should also consider, what happens if `err` is not an `AxiosError`. Then your `fetchAllProducts` won't return anything and you will try to destructure a value of `undefined`, which will throw a runtime error.

Comment: `export type Products = {
  data?: ProductProps[];
  error?: string;
}`
is a better type instead of `data: ProductProps[] | null;` ?

Comment: @khewdev Yes, may be, depends on OP's usecase ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `catch` function, since if `if(err instanceof AxiosError)` condition **does not** fulfill, `fetchAllProducts` function will return `undefined`.

You should add a fallback `{}` return.

**[Typescript demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA3jAJgQysgNDApgJxyHGAXwC4YAFfRAV2CghgF4ZkB3ZAS1gDMspgAFgEEANiMogadCAAoAlAG4YAKBgqsADwAOBWFACeWrBSq16TeKrVJUyMhKlQJWiAG0AujAA+MMNTEKVmq4+DgA-GTQOBxgAOaBRIHKypo6OHqGxg5mzgzMcEEwHIiRUNFxgdYwUFwiWKXl8YXAqFixBPoNMU1ViFgQwNFaNeBdFYUcALbIsfUwUd2V1lrRwHN+kwBGuEtqOKjdZAVVVftQ69RbuOiFVaDUYFBkG9s4hUTKHynauiwQ+mBgDBuA86BxwMC+IJROJTNJ5JY1GV9IjrKBILAcP0LGxOLBkBpwRAAHSzKAyag4ESKZrgaA2NAWLEklBoXYwLFQSlgVG9WzvKxEFr8AQyEJyXlFbhivBFDHIQFYEDcGBCQkgCAAUTwBAlxxOnO5kqqIQIZBCxMm-QgMywNxO1lZdl8-hE9pOHyqX1OfCN+r5aGervdak9xE+QA)**

```
catch(err) {
  if (err instanceof AxiosError) {
    return {
      error: err.message,
    };
  }

  return {
     error: 'fallback error',
  };
}
```

Comment: But now I get this error: `Type '{ data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: string; data?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Products'.
  Type '{ data: any; error?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Products'.
    Property 'error' is optional in type '{ data: any; error?: undefined; }' but required in type 'Products'.` I can make error to be optional but what should I do with data

Comment: @Lilly You can either make them both optional, or in case of error, pass `data` as null. Check my updated typescript link.